# C++ undirected graphs

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph

I've searched a lot over the past few days on this theme and I don't understand how could I make an undirected graph without having a weight. Can anybody tell me which structure should I use and a simple algorithm? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Is this homework?

Comment: A simple algorithm to do what?

Comment: What does weight have to do with it? Have you tried implementing an edge as a pair of pointers between two nodes, one in each direction? An what do you want the "simple algorithm" to *do*?

Answer (score 6):

There isn't any specific requirement that forces you to give weights to your edges. Your adjacency matrix could have binary entries 1-0 or true-false to specify a connection between nodes. All graph algorithms apply as normal.

A VERY helpful lecture about graphs: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ylWAB6CMYiY

Comment: Could you make it with linked lists? By a simple algorithm I mean the basic functions or elements needed

Comment: @Yiyi A graph is a unique data structure on its own. The nodes are indeed "linked" but the implementation is different than linked lists. I suggest that you look at some university lectures on youtube (maybe the MIT or UCBerkley channel) in case you are starting out. This prof is great http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ylWAB6CMYiY. Check it out

Answer (score 0):

In a slight elaboration on P.R.s answer. The standard matrix representation can easily be interpreted as the top (north-east) being from top to left (B to A), left being left to top (south-west, none here). A one (1) in any position (boolean internally perhaps) would indicate an unweighted connection.

```
x A B C D
A 0 1 0 0
B 0 0 1 1
C 0 0 0 1 
D 0 0 0 0
```

Would imply that A is connected to no nodes. B is connected to A. C is connected to B. D is connected to B and C.

This particular example would create a tree with D as the root with children B and C, A as a child to B. A and C leafs.

Note that the unweighted property really does not simplify much. Only in a pure pointer implementation exercise, but that is quite pointless [FAPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_All_Practical_Purposes). An `adjacency list` instead of this `adjacency matrix` might give you memory usage advantages.